# Iterate over items in a Counter by counts

Tags: python, counter

Let's say I have a `Counter` object: `Counter({'test': 2, 'this': 1, 'is': 1})`

I would like to iterate over this object in the following way:

```
c = Counter({'test': 2, 'this': 1, 'is': 1})

for i,s in my_counter_iterator(c):
    print i, ":", s

>> 1 : ['this', 'is']
>> 2 : ['test']
```

How do I do that efficiently (this code should run on a web server for each request...)?

*EDIT*

I have tried this, but I have the feeling there are more efficient ways. Are there?

```
from itertools import groupby

for k,g in groupby(sorted(c.keys(), key=lambda x: c[x]),key=lambda x: c[x]):
    print k, list(g)


1 ['this', 'is']
2 ['test']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do this with large `Counter`s, you really have no choice but to invert the mapping.

```
inv_c = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in c.iteritems():
    inv_c[v].append(k)
```

Then `inv_c.iteritems()` is what you want.

Comment: Is this more efficient than sorting and grouping with `groupby`?

Comment: In an asymptotic sense, yes.  Sorting is O(nlogn) and this operation is O(n).  Is it faster in your case?  Only experimentation will tell you. :-)

Comment: of course it is... it just takes ~twice the memory but it's ok.

Comment: @zenpoy: sorting with `sorted` takes at least O(n) memory as well. In fact, you can't do this in less memory, asymptotically.